# C++ maps and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl, hashmap, stdmap

I am having to recreate a map every single time instead of just referencing the already created one.

This works:

```
void render(Scene *scene) {

     map<std::string, Node*> _map = scene->getNodes(); // I don't want recreate the map every time. It is slowing down the render function :(
     for(auto outer_iter = _map.begin(); outer_iter!= _map.end(); ++outer_iter) {
         outer_iter->second->draw(*scene->getCamera());
     }
}
```

But this doesn't....

```
 void render(Scene *scene) {

     //map<std::string, Node*> _map = scene->getNodes();
     for(auto outer_iter = scene->getNodes().begin(); outer_iter!= scene->getNodes().end(); ++outer_iter) {
         outer_iter->second->draw(*scene->getCamera());
     }
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening really.

How can I just reference the map that is in Scene without recreating it every single time?

Comment: What error is this showing?

Comment: `map<std::string, Node*>` such design calls more for a [managed pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return the map by const reference and change to `const map<std::string, Node*> &_map`:

```
class Scene{
    map<std::string, Node*> map;
public:
    const map<std::string, Node*>& getNodes() const{
        return map;
    }
}

void render(Scene *scene) {

     const map<std::string, Node*> &_map = scene->getNodes(); 
     for(auto outer_iter = _map.begin(); outer_iter!= _map.end(); ++outer_iter) {
         outer_iter->second->draw(*scene->getCamera());
     }
}
```

This will avoid the copy each `render` call and just operates on the map n